# INTEL XDK Ajax response is not working

Tags: javascript, html, intel, cordova-plugins, intel-xdk

I am just start working in INTEL XDK after almost one year.I have  created 20-21 android apps.Now I had downloaded aIntel xdk new version about 3 months ago.and now I have downloaded the latest version of intel xdk.

I have created an apk which was based on ajax call,The apk was working fine in emulator,testing as well as debugging through device, but while I have created an apk it is not working in my device.

For that I have tried so many sollutions , suggestions which are given on web,added xhr.js etc..but it was no working properly.

But When I have created again with old XDK perhapes it was verson 1621 or older than it, it is working properly.

So with the latest version of XDK I am facing issue with ajax but not in old version.What should be the problem with latest version of XDK?
My current version is **1912**

Here is my code STRUCTURE
[image]

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Blank App Designer Cordova Web App Project Template</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <style>
                @-ms-viewport { width: 100vw ; min-zoom: 100% ; zoom: 100% ; }          @viewport { width: 100vw ; min-zoom: 100% zoom: 100% ; }
                @-ms-viewport { user-zoom: fixed ; min-zoom: 100% ; }                   @viewport { user-zoom: fixed ; min-zoom: 100% ; }
                /*@-ms-viewport { user-zoom: zoom ; min-zoom: 100% ; max-zoom: 200% ; }   @viewport { user-zoom: zoom ; min-zoom: 100% ; max-zoom: 200% ; }*/
        </style>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index_main.less.css" class="main-less">
        <script src="jquery/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="cordova.js" id="xdkJScordova_"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <!-- for your event code, see README and file comments for details -->
        <script src="js/init-app.js"></script>
        <!-- for your init code, see README and file comments for details -->
        <script src="xdk/init-dev.js"></script>
        <script src='xhr.js'></script>
        <!-- normalizes device and document ready events, see file for details -->
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="upage vertical-col" id="mainpage">
            <div class="grid grid-pad urow uib_row_1 row-height-1" data-uib="layout/row" data-ver="0">
                <div class="col uib_col_1 col-0_12-12" data-uib="layout/col" data-ver="0">
                    <div class="widget-container content-area vertical-col">
                        <span class="uib_shim"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <span class="uib_shim"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="grid grid-pad urow uib_row_3 row-height-3" data-uib="layout/row" data-ver="0">
                <div class="col uib_col_3 col-0_12-12" data-uib="layout/col" data-ver="0">
                    <div class="widget-container content-area vertical-col">

                        <div class="table-thing widget uib_w_1 d-margins" data-uib="twitter%20bootstrap/input" data-ver="1">
                            <label class="narrow-control label-top-left">User Name</label>
                            <input class="wide-control form-control default" type="text" placeholder="User Name">
                        </div><span class="uib_shim"></span>
                        <div class="table-thing widget uib_w_1 d-margins" data-uib="twitter%20bootstrap/input" data-ver="1">
                            <label class="narrow-control label-top-left">Password</label>
                            <input class="wide-control form-control default" type="text" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                        <button class="btn widget uib_w_2 d-margins btn-default" data-uib="twitter%20bootstrap/button" data-ver="1" id="login"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok button-icon-left" data-position="left"></i>Login</button><span class="uib_shim"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <span class="uib_shim"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
        $("#login").click(function(){
         $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:'http://time.jsontest.com/',
        error: function(response, d, a){
            alert(response + d + a) ;  
        },
        success: function (response){
            alert(JSON.stringify(response));        
        }
    });
        });
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a known ajax issue with apk built with latest Intel XDK on Android > 4.4, this is due to the version of Cordova CLI 4.1.2.

In the Intel XDK -> project settings -> build settings for Android, change the Cordova CLI version to 3.5 and ajax should work again. We are working on a fix when using latest CLI

Comment: Thank You, right now I have installed the old version, soon I will re-install the new version and try.

Answer (score 1):

@Hardik, There are some changes in the Cordova 4.1.2 security model and hence you have to use proper settings in the Build Settings of Intel XDK. Please read [this article](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/cordova-cli-412-domain-whitelisting-with-intel-xdk-for-ajax-and-launching-external-apps) to find out how you should set the build settings before you build your app.